# Получить значение поля поля вложенного класса

Tags: java, рефлексия, inner

Есть некий внешний и внутренний класс

```
 public class OuterClass {

int a = 20;
public class InnerClass {
    String name1="123!!!";}}
```

И реализация в main

```
OuterClass obj = new OuterClass();

   Class[] classes = obj.getClass().getDeclaredClasses();
    for(Class innerClass: classes){
        System.out.println(innerClass.getName());
        Field[] fields = innerClass.getDeclaredFields();
        for(Field field : fields){
            System.out.println(field.getName());

            try {
                System.out.println(field.get(innerClass)); //<-----IllegalArgumentException
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Как получить значения поля внутреннего класса не делая их static?

Comment: с внешним классом get() работает без проблем с внутренним вылезает ошибка IllegalArgumentException

Comment: Чтобы создать экземпляр внутреннего класса, необходимо сначала создать экземпляр внешнего класса. OuterClass.InnerClass obj = obj.new InnerClas();

Comment: [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поскольку InnerClass не инициализирован на момент исполнения Вашего кода, вы можете считать только названия полей. Если необходимо считать значения по умолчанию, сначало инициализируем внутренний класс:

```
public class Outer {
    int a;

    public class Inner {
        String name1 = "123!!!";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Outer outer = new Outer();
        Class[] classes = outer.getClass().getDeclaredClasses();
        for (Class innerClass : classes) {
            System.out.println(innerClass.getName());
            Field[] fields = innerClass.getDeclaredFields();

            Constructor constructor = innerClass.getDeclaredConstructor(outer.getClass());
            Object innerInstance = constructor.newInstance(outer);

            for (Field field : fields) {
                System.out.println(field.getName());
                field.setAccessible(true);
                try {
                    System.out.println(field.get(innerInstance));
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Результат:

```
aug.Outer$Inner
name1
123!!!
this$0
aug.Outer@29453f44
```

Comment: Спасибо помогло) А конструктор надо вызывать только так руками?